# Bacula multiple storage device

Tags: bacula

It seems to be relatively a simple question. I have two mount points on bacula-sd (storage) server-  one for local drive and one for s3 bucket (off side backup) and what I need is start two concurrent job at the same time on both drives. So far I have something like that in bacula devices.conf

```
   Device {
      Name            = "example.prod.com"
      Device Type     = File
      Media Type      = File
      Archive Device  = "/data/bacula/example.prod.com"
      LabelMedia      = yes
      Random Access   = yes
      AutomaticMount  = yes
      RemovableMedia  = no
      AlwaysOpen      = no
      Maximum Network Buffer Size = 65536
   }

   Device {
      Name = example.prod.com-s3
      Device Type = File
      Media Type = File
      Archive Device = "/mnt/bacula-backup-storage/example.prod.com-s3"
      LabelMedia = yes
      Random Access = Yes
      AutomaticMount = yes
      RemovableMedia = no
      AlwaysOpen = no
      Maximum Network Buffer Size = 65536
   }
```

but it's probably not enough because the job started only on the first device. Do I need disk autochanger or something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `Media Type = ...` parameter to be different for both Devices, i.e.

```
Device {
      Name            = "example.prod.com"
      Device Type     = File
      Media Type      = File
...
}

Device {
      Name = example.prod.com-s3
      Device Type = File
      Media Type = S3
...
}
```

It won't work otherwise.